# Nested Select Query Refactoring and translating to Eloquent / Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, fluent, query-builder

Step 1: Get the maximum set_id from the table. set_id is not unique.

```
select max(set_id) from mytable where ver = 6;
# assume returns 3
```

Step 2: Get the results from the table where set_id is max:

```
select * from mytable where ver = 6 and set_id = 3;
# from step 1
```

Step 3: Refactoring / nesting the select statements

```
select * from mytable where ver = 6 and set_id = 
    ( select max(set_id) from mytable where ver = 6 );
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing this statement?

How can I translate this statement to Eloquent / Fluent query builder?

Answer (score 1):

I would write that statement like this:

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE ver=6 ORDER BY set_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

which would translate to:

```
DB::table('mytable')->where('ver', 6)->orderBy('set_id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, but your answer is not correct. I am not looking for one result.

Comment: That means that max set_Id is not unique and can be found in more than one entries. I assumed there is only one entry with set_id =3.

Comment: Yes - set_id is not unique. If it was, then I would not need to do a nested select.

Answer (score 0):

You can create more advanced `where` clauses:

```
DB::table('mytable')
    ->where('ver', '=', 6)
    ->where('set_id', '=', function($query)
    {
        $query->from('mytable')
              ->select(DB::raw('max(set_id)'))
              ->where('ver', '=', 6);
    })
    ->get();
```